# Fuse file system with "default permission" option

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, redhat, fuse

I am new to fuse. I have mounted fuse by the following command.

```
/mnt/fuse -o default_permissions -o allow_other -o nonempty -o hard_remove –d
```

Now If I login as "test" user and tried to create a file called "testfile".

```
test@11540302:/registration> touch testfile
touch: setting times of `testfile': Permission denied
```

Strace output:

```
uname({sys="Linux", node="11540302", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8055000
brk(0x8076000)                          = 0x8076000
open("testfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) =    3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)             = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
close(0)                                = 0
```

But "testfile" creation is successful with owner as **root** user,

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root trusted     0 Jan 19 13:51 testfile
```

I can understand that fuse application is running in root level, file creation happened with the owner as root. Because of that test user cannot perform any operation on "testfile".

**My question:**

**Since I have given "allow_other" while mounting, why test user cannot having privileges to access the "testfile"?**

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww this question is definitely about programming and development, specifically programming a user-space filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this problem.

[Detailed explanation for this issue.](https://lwn.net/Articles/131856/)

Solution:

As @dirkt said we need to handle permissions on our own.

**Code to get the caller uid and gid:**

> fuse_get_context()->uid;
>
> fuse_get_context()->gid;

Get the caller user id and group id and set the ownership of the file/directory while creating via fuse API's.

Always there is room for improvement. Kindly correct me if I am not correct.

Thank you dirkt for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `test` user to the `fuse` group:

```
usermod -a -G fuse test
```

Also, make sure that `#user_allow_other` is uncommented on the `fuse` configuration file (generally on `/etc/fuse.conf`):

```
sed -i -e "s/#user_allow_other/user_allow_other/gi" /etc/fuse.conf
```

After running either of those, `reboot` the computer and try again.